# how to edit/delete records in a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this code for the deleting of records in a datagridview using VB.NET and SQL -12

```
 Private Sub Delete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("delete this item?", "DELETE!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        Me.DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.DataGridView.CurrentRow.)
    Else
        DataGridView.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I'm using this, the record only gets deleted temporarily but not permanently from the database. How should I delete the records permanently?
The same is the case when I'm editing a field. It's just temporary.

Comment: How are you populating the datagridview, are you using a datatable and a dataadapater ?

Comment: I'm using an SQL command, a data adapted and dataset

Answer (score 0):

Then you set the deletecommand for the sqldataadapter. The code depends on your table's KeyID name and type, among other things.

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection 
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
...
(here you wrote the dataadapter Fill code)
...
Dim cmdDelete As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE KeyID = @KeyID", connection)
cmdDelete.Parameters.Add("@KeyID", SqlDbType.NChar, 8, "KeyID")
adapter.DeleteCommand = command
```

I think the dataadapter wizard should have done this for you though.