# Automatically delete rows with Sunday Date

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Hello guyz please help.

From snapshot above the "Date" column has sunday date "3/17/2017" and "3/26/2017". I want to delete row with Sunday in the column of "Date" automatically when I imported an attendance log to the datagridview.

so far my code is just to delete one by one:

```
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblEmployeeAttendance WHERE [Date] = '3/17/2017' "
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

but I want to delete upon load to the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change date

```
While fromatafter.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse fromatafter.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday
    fromatafter = fromatafter.AddDays(-1)
    End While
    dates.Add(fromatafter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

You need to assigne the date returned from dates to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepart function for sql command
    DELETE FROM tblEmployeeAttendance WHERE Datepart(dw,[Date])=1

Comment: how to delete upon load to the datagridview?

Comment: look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897181/how-to-edit-delete-records-in-a-datagridview, maybe can help, also you can use filter in datagridview to hide some records